# what happens when we deploy lambda resource without attaching vpc?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm learning AWS, I created a lambda resource using AWS cloudformation. But I created the aws-lambda without attaching vpc or subnet to the lambda.
Even if I didn't attach lambda to VPC, will this lambda gets created in default VPC?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the default VPC that the lambda launched into isn't the default VPC in your account. It's a VPC managed by AWS.

Comment: When we create an AWS account, AWS itself will provide a default vpc. You mean, lambda doesn’t exist in this vpc?

Comment: This is correct. It's not in the default VPC in your account. It is in another AWS managed VPC.

Comment: Thank you, I was googling but couldn’t find the answer.

Comment: Can you please point me to aws documentation from where did you refer this point?